# How to dynamically change text which has Cufon applied to it

Tags: jquery, cufon

I am working on a site which has Cufon applied to it. Before cufon, I have the following markup:

```
<label class="option" for="edit-delivery-method-U.S.-postal-delivery">
  <input type="radio" id="edit-delivery-method-U.S.-postal-delivery" name="delivery-method" value="U.S. postal delivery" checked="checked" class="form-radio" />
  U.S. postal delivery 
</label>
```

After Cufon, the text was replaced with 4 Cufon->canvas tags, replacing each word of text.

```
<label class="option" for="edit-delivery-method-U.S.-postal-delivery">
<input type="radio" id="edit-delivery-method-U.S.-postal-delivery" name="delivery-method" value="U.S. postal delivery" checked="checked" class="form-radio"> 
<cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt=" " style="width: 4px; height: 14px;"><canvas width="20" height="17" style="width: 20px; height: 17px; top: -2px; left: -2px;"></canvas><cufontext> </cufontext></cufon>
<cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="U.S. " style="width: 25px; height: 14px;"><canvas width="41" height="17" style="width: 41px; height: 17px; top: -2px; left: -2px;"></canvas><cufontext>U.S. </cufontext></cufon>
<cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="postal " style="width: 39px; height: 14px;"><canvas width="54" height="17" style="width: 54px; height: 17px; top: -2px; left: -2px;"></canvas><cufontext>postal </cufontext></cufon>
<cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="delivery" style="width: 46px; height: 14px;"><canvas width="59" height="17" style="width: 59px; height: 17px; top: -2px; left: -2px;"></canvas><cufontext>delivery</cufontext></cufon>
</label>
```

I would like to dynamically change this text on a click event. I don't see how I can target this properly with jQuery to change the text. When looking at the Cufon API here https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/API, I found something which I thought might work but its not working for me. Here is my code:

```
 var usPostalOneYearLabel = $('#edit-delivery-method-U.S.-postal-delivery-wrapper label');
var deliveryMethod = $('input[name="delivery-method"]');
deliveryMethod.change(function() {
    if(deliveryMethod.filter(':checked').val() === "U.S. postal delivery") {
        console.log('yay!');
        var html = usPostalOneYearLabel.html();
        Cufon.replace(usPostalOneYearLabel, {
            modifyText: function() {
                return 'hello world';
            }
        });
        Cufon.refresh(usPostalOneYearLabel);
        console.log('html');
    }
});
```

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

Comment: It looks like Cufon.replace and Cufon.refresh take the first parameter of the id, class, or other CSS reference to your object. You are passing in the jQuery object itself (should pass in string '#edit-delivery-method-u.s.-postal-delivery-wrapper' where you are passing the object $('#edit-delivery-method-u.s.-postal-delivery-wrapper'). I'd try removing $() from the first line of your javascript and see if that works.

Answer (score 1):

I  have found the solution :

First : replace alt attribute of the cufon tag.

```
<cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Home"
```

to :

```
<cufon class="cufon cufon-canvas" alt="Lorem"
```

Second execute in javascript :

```
Cufon.replace('.menu-item a');
```

in my case. (to be applicate for each element to replace)